# throw err; Error: Cannot find module 'node-rdkafka'

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

**This is my traceback:**

I am trying to run a project which uses apache-kafka as a simple messaging 
queue, with single producer-broker-consumer. However, I have kafka_2.12-0.11.0.0 version.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'node-rdkafka'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/junaid/eMumba/CASB/git/casb-cleansers/server/index.js:2:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
at loader (/home/junaid/eMumba/CASB/git/casb-cleansers/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/junaid/eMumba/CASB/git/casb-cleansers/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-112-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! a10-casb-cleanser@1.0.0 start: `babel-node ./server/index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the a10-casb-cleanser@1.0.0 start script 'babel-    node ./server/index.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm     installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the a10-casb-    cleanser package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     babel-node ./server/index.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this     project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs a10-casb-cleanser
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls a10-casb-cleanser
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/junaid/eMumba/CASB/git/casb-cleansers/npm-debug.lo
```

I have tried the solution mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999276/throw-err-cannot-find-module-node-rdkafka) by opening terminal in this directory:

```
/home/junaid/eMumba/CASB/git/casb-cleansers/server/
```

and in terminal:

```
npm install --save node-rdkafka
```

**This is traceback after running the above command:**

```
WARN engine node-rdkafka@2.2.1: wanted: {"npm":"^2.7.3"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6","npm":"3.5.2"})
WARN engine node-rdkafka@2.2.1: wanted: {"npm":"^2.7.3"} (current:     {"node":"4.2.
> node-rdkafka@2.2.1 preinstall /home/junaid/eMumba/CASB/git/casb-    cleansers/node_modules/.staging/node-rdkafka-323ea092
> node util/configure

checking for OS or distribution... ok (Ubuntu)
checking for C compiler from CC env... failed
checking for gcc (by command)... ok
checking for C++ compiler from CXX env... failed
checking for C++ compiler (g++)... ok
checking executable ld... ok
checking executable nm... ok
checking executable objdump... ok
checking executable strip... ok
checking for pkgconfig (by command)... ok
checking for install (by command)... ok
checking for PIC (by compile)... ok
checking for GNU-compatible linker options... ok
checking for GNU linker-script ld flag... ok
checking for __atomic_32 (by compile)... ok
checking for __atomic_64 (by compile)... ok
checking for socket (by compile)... ok
parsing version '0x000b01ff'... ok (0.11.1)
checking for libpthread (by pkg-config)... failed
checking for libpthread (by compile)... ok
checking for zlib (by pkg-config)... ok
checking for zlib (by compile)... ok (cached)
checking for libcrypto (by pkg-config)... ok
checking for libcrypto (by compile)... ok (cached)
checking for liblz4 (by pkg-config)... failed
checking for liblz4 (by compile)... failed (disable)
checking for libssl (by pkg-config)... ok
checking for libssl (by compile)... ok (cached)
checking for libsasl2 (by pkg-config)... failed
checking for libsasl2 (by compile)... failed (disable)
checking for libsasl (by pkg-config)... failed
checking for libsasl (by compile)... failed (disable)
checking for crc32chw (by compile)... ok
checking for regex (by compile)... ok
checking for librt (by pkg-config)... failed
checking for librt (by compile)... ok
checking for strndup (by compile)... ok
checking for strerror_r (by compile)... ok
checking for libdl (by pkg-config)... failed
checking for libdl (by compile)... ok
checking for nm (by env NM)... ok (cached)
checking for python (by command)... ok
Generated Makefile.config
Generated config.h

Configuration summary:
  prefix                   /usr/local
  ARCH                     x86_64
  CPU                      generic
  GEN_PKG_CONFIG           y
  ENABLE_DEVEL             n
  ENABLE_VALGRIND          n
  ENABLE_REFCNT_DEBUG      n
  ENABLE_SHAREDPTR_DEBUG   n
  ENABLE_LZ4_EXT           y
  ENABLE_SSL               y
  ENABLE_SASL              y
  MKL_APP_NAME             librdkafka
  MKL_APP_DESC_ONELINE     The Apache Kafka C/C++ library
  MKL_DISTRO               Ubuntu
  SOLIB_EXT                .so
  CC                       gcc
  CXX                      g++
  LD                       ld
  NM                       nm
  OBJDUMP                  objdump
  STRIP                    strip
  CPPFLAGS                 -g -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-    equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align
  PKG_CONFIG               pkg-config
  INSTALL                  install
  LIB_LDFLAGS              -shared -Wl,-soname,$(LIBFILENAME)
  LDFLAG_LINKERSCRIPT      -Wl,--version-script=
  RDKAFKA_VERSION_STR      0.11.1
  MKL_APP_VERSION          0.11.1
  LIBS                     -lpthread -lz -lcrypto -lssl -lrt -ldl
  CFLAGS                   
  CXXFLAGS                 -Wno-non-virtual-dtor
  SYMDUMPER                $(NM) -D
  exec_prefix              /usr/local
  bindir                   /usr/local/bin
  sbindir                  /usr/local/sbin
  libexecdir               /usr/local/libexec
  datadir                  /usr/local/share
  sysconfdir               /usr/local/etc
  sharedstatedir           /usr/local/com
  localstatedir            /usr/local/var
  libdir                   /usr/local/lib
  includedir               /usr/local/include
  infodir                  /usr/local/info
  mandir                   /usr/local/man
Generated config.cache

Now type 'make' to build

> node-rdkafka@2.2.1 install /home/junaid/eMumba/CASB/git/casb-    cleansers/node_modules/node-rdkafka
> node-gyp rebuild

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/home/junaid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-        20.3-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2900, in <module>
  File "/home/junaid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-    20.3-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2886, in _call_aside
  File "/home/junaid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-    20.3-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in     _initialize_master_working_set
  File "/home/junaid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-    20.3-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 642, in _build_master
  File "/home/junaid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.3-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 943, in require
  File "/home/junaid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-    20.3-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 830, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'gyp==0.1' distribution was     not found and is required by the application
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/share/node-        gyp/lib/configure.js:354:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit     (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-112-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/junaid/eMumba/CASB/git/casb-    cleansers/node_modules/node-rdkafka
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.6
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency     /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or     architecture: fsevents@1.1.3
npm WARN a10-casb-cleanser@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-112-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--save"     "node-rdkafka"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-rdkafka@2.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-rdkafka@2.2.1 install script 'node-gyp     rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm     installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-    rdkafka package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this     project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs node-rdkafka
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-rdkafka
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/junaid/eMumba/CASB/git/casb-cleansers/server/npm-    debug.log
```

If anyone can help me with this. I have been trying to solve this for quite some time now, thanks.

Comment: I experienced this behavior on macOS Mojave. Exporting the flags defined here https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rdkafka#mac-os-high-sierra--mojave resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score -2):

this sometimes happen with npm and caching.

Be sure to run those:

- rm -rf node_modules
- npm install
- npm install --save node-rdkafka

Comment: I have tried this and I am still getting the same traceback.